# Is meta tag [review-ban] different from [review-suspension]?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, synonym-request, meta

[review-ban](/questions/tagged/review-ban) tag wiki excerpt says:

> A review ban prevents a user from participating in a specific review queue.

[review-suspension](/questions/tagged/review-suspension) excerpt says:

> Questions involving review bans/suspensions.

Questions in these tags all appear to be covering same topics

Is there a point of having them as separate tags, would it make sense to make them synonyms?

Comment: Not that I can see - and the tag wiki is wrong anyway - review suspensions are not queue specific

Comment: @JonClements They aren't? I thought that they were (at least when imposed by the system)

Comment: @Zizouz212 unlike Q & A which are "bans" in the sense there isn't really a time limit in which they naturally expire and more that an action is required to lift it. Review "bans" are more suspensions, whether they're system/moderator imposed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Nope - not that I can see - and it's more a "suspension" than a "ban", so:

[review-ban](/questions/tagged/review-ban) is now a syn. of [review-suspension](/questions/tagged/review-suspension).

Comment: I worked over the tag-wiki for it here and on [meta.se].